# How to merge two dataframes by shared column based on dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, join, merge

so I have two dataframes I am trying to join by a single column. However, this common column is different between both dataframes, where the values in one dataframe are full names, and the values in the other dataframe are abbreviations. I am trying to make some sort of mapping dictionary that equates the names to their abbreviations, so the dataframes can be directly joined by this common column. I will explain further below.

I have this dataframe (A):

```
    Building         Style           CO2       NOx
---------------------------------------------------
Multi-Family             A            34        55
Multi-Family             B            43        44
Multi-Family             C            33        35 
Single-Family            A            34        26
Single-Family            B            22        26
Single-Family            C            65        48
Single-Family            D            55        74 
Studio                   A            46        35 
Studio                   B            54        67
Studio                   C            57        58
```

And then I have this dataframe (B):

```
Building   Style    Zip_code     Number
---------------------------------------
      MF       A       11111         4 
      MF       A       22222         3
      MF       A       33333         2
      MF       B       11111         1
      MF       B       22222         1
      MF       C       22222         1 
      MF       C       33333         6
      SF       A       11111         7 
      SF       A       22222         5
      SF       B       44444         3
      SF       B       55555         8 
      SF       B       66666         6
      SF       C       11111         9
      SF       C       22222         9
      ST       A       33333         3
      ST       A       44444         5
      ST       B       55555         5
      ST       B       66666         3
      ST       C       11111         2 
      ST       C       22222         9 
      ST       C       33333         1
```

Now I want to create the following dataframe (C):

```
Zip_code      CO2    NOx
-------------------------
11111           ?      ?
22222           ?      ?
33333           ?      ?
44444           ?      ?
55555           ?      ?
66666           ?      ?
```

I will explain this further. I have data for buildings that shows CO2 and NOx emissions for 3 styles of buildings corresponding to 3 types of buildings (Dataframe A). I then have data that shows how many of each of these types of homes there are in each of the listed zip codes (Dataframe B). I ultimately want to create a dataframe that shows total emissions for each zip code, both for CO2 and NOx (Dataframe C). The idea behind getting Dataframe C is that I want to produce a dataframe that can then be joined to a GIS shapefile by zip code, so I can then map CO2 and NOx emissions in each zip code, having acquired a blank zipcodes shapefile to be joined to. (I realize that mapping emissions is much more complex than this, but I am keeping this simple for this stage in my project).

So what I am trying to do is join Dataframe A to Dataframe B on the "Building" column. The issue though is that the "Building" column in Dataframe A has the names in full, while the "Building" column in Dataframe B has the names as abbreviations. I am thinking I need to create some sort of dictionary that matches the full name to its abbreviation to be referred to, but I am not sure how to fit that in here.

Can this be done in python? Or is this actually way more complex than I am making this out to be? I have spent hours upon hours trying to wrap my head around how to merge these two dataframes, but each time I just get more confused. I am having a lot of trouble conceptualizing what this code would look like, even if the goal may seem simple. I would appreciate any help or guidance with this! Apologies for making these dataframes so long, but I felt it was necessary to capture the structure/complexity of the data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible. You can indeed first turn the Buildings names into abbreviations using a custom function that splits on the hyphen and takes the first letter of each word. Then you can merge the dataframes on both `Building` and `Style`. Finally you can `groupby` on `Zip-code`:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [ { "Building": "Multi-Family", "Style": "A", "CO2": 34, "NOx": 55 }, { "Building": "Multi-Family", "Style": "B", "CO2": 43, "NOx": 44 }, { "Building": "Multi-Family", "Style": "C", "CO2": 33, "NOx": 35 }, { "Building": "Single-Family", "Style": "A", "CO2": 34, "NOx": 26 }, { "Building": "Single-Family", "Style": "B", "CO2": 22, "NOx": 26 }, { "Building": "Single-Family", "Style": "C", "CO2": 65, "NOx": 48 }, { "Building": "Single-Family", "Style": "D", "CO2": 55, "NOx": 74 }, { "Building": "Studio", "Style": "A", "CO2": 46, "NOx": 35 }, { "Building": "Studio", "Style": "B", "CO2": 54, "NOx": 67 }, { "Building": "Studio", "Style": "C", "CO2": 57, "NOx": 58 } ]
data2 = [ { "Building": "MF", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 11111, "Number": 4 }, { "Building": "MF", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 22222, "Number": 3 }, { "Building": "MF", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 33333, "Number": 2 }, { "Building": "MF", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 11111, "Number": 1 }, { "Building": "MF", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 22222, "Number": 1 }, { "Building": "MF", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 22222, "Number": 1 }, { "Building": "MF", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 33333, "Number": 6 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 11111, "Number": 7 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 22222, "Number": 5 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 44444, "Number": 3 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 55555, "Number": 8 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 66666, "Number": 6 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 11111, "Number": 9 }, { "Building": "SF", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 22222, "Number": 9 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 33333, "Number": 3 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "A", "Zip_code": 44444, "Number": 5 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 55555, "Number": 5 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "B", "Zip_code": 66666, "Number": 3 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 11111, "Number": 2 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 22222, "Number": 9 }, { "Building": "ST", "Style": "C", "Zip_code": 33333, "Number": 1 } ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

def shorten_buildings(text):
    text = ''.join([i[0] for i in text.split('-')])
    return text if text != 'S' else 'ST'

df1['Building'] = df1['Building'].apply(shorten_buildings)

df2 = df2.merge(df1,  how='left', on=['Building','Style'])

df2['CO2'] = df2['Number'] * df2['CO2'] #total CO2
df2['NOx'] = df2['Number'] * df2['NOx'] #total NOx
df2.groupby(['Zip_code']).sum().drop('Number', axis=1)
```

Output:

| Zip_code | CO2 | NOx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 1116 | 994 |
| 22222 | 1446 | 1328 |
| 33333 | 461 | 483 |
| 44444 | 296 | 253 |
| 55555 | 446 | 543 |
| 66666 | 294 | 357 |